# How to disable the right bar button of navigation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = FALSE;
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
//[myview sendSubviewToBack:self.view];
//self.view.hidden= TRUE;
myview.hidden= FALSE;
activityIndicator.hidden= FALSE;
dt = [[DateTime alloc] init];
```

This is my method in this when user click on leftbar button of navigation this method fires here i want to disable the button but its not getting disable and i checked my code i am not enabling it anywhere.......Please help me

Comment: Sorry i bymistakely gave wrong title help for Rightbar button and not left

Comment: So you want to disable the 'back' button? If that is all the navigation bar is showing you could just hide it all together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If properties aren't initialised properly in Objective-C you won't see any errors, the statement just won't get executed..

My first guess would be that you're calling a method on a nil reference.

Use the debugger to see whether the rightBarButtonItem has been set up properly.

Answer (score 21):

Just

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: hmmh, didn't work for me, right or left bar button returns nil while there clearly is a button :(